# Using .load() to check when iframe is loaded, problems with jquery slider/carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, onload

I have this jquery carousel i have created witch contains four iframes.

Im creating a page where the content of the sub-pages is loaded dynamicly with jquery, and when i open the "video" section of the page im using a loading icon while the page load to improve the user experience.

I have set a class to the first iframe, and using that class to check if the content is loaded before setting the container div to visible and hiding the loader icon.

//List of videos, js

```
var videoList = new Array();
videoList[0] = "N8pwUMuS8S0";
videoList[1] = "NYV_ru0Ra8I";
videoList[2] = "uwQT-r-lXWg";
videoList[3] = "RKtRL7FkjQA";
```

//Dynamicly created sub-page, js

```
function addMusicVideos(){
        htmlTekst = "<div id='divRedLine'></div>";
        htmlTekst += "<div class='headerTekst'><h2>Music videos</h2></div>";
        htmlTekst += "<div id='carousel'>"
        htmlTekst += "<div id='buttons'><img id='next' src='bilder/arrow-right.png' alt='next' /><img id='prev' src='bilder/arrow-left.png' /><div class='clear'></div></div>";
        htmlTekst += "<div id='slides'>";
        htmlTekst += "<ul>";
        htmlTekst += "<li><div class='videoContainer'><iframe class='firstVid' class='videoPlayer' width='100%' height='100%' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ videoList[0] +"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div></li>";
        htmlTekst += "<li><div class='videoContainer'><iframe class='videoPlayer' width='100%' height='100%' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ videoList[1] +"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div></li>";
        htmlTekst += "<li><div class='videoContainer'><iframe class='videoPlayer' width='100%' height='100%' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ videoList[2] +"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div></li>";
        htmlTekst += "<li><div class='videoContainer'><iframe class='videoPlayer' width='100%' height='100%' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ videoList[3] +"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div></li>";
        htmlTekst += "</ul>";
        htmlTekst += "</div></div>";
        $('#content').html(htmlTekst)
        $("#bgBlack").css({"display":"block"})
        $('#secBottom').css({"opacity":"0.5"})
        iframLoad();

    };

function iframLoad(){
    $(".firstVid").on('load',function(){
        $("#content").css({"visibility":"visible"});
        $('.spinner').css({"display":"none"})
        loadContenet();
    });
}
```

JS SLIDEHOW:

```
window.loadContenet = function(){
    item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(); 
    left_value = item_width * (-1); 

    $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));
    $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
}
   $('#content').on('click', '#prev', function(event) {

        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

        $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 800,function(){             
            $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           
            $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});        
        });    
        return false; 
    });

    $('#content').on('click', '#next', function(event) {

        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) - item_width;

        $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 800, function () {         
            $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  
            $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value}); 
        });

        return false;   
    });
```

My problem is that every time the carousel has finished and stats on a new "round" it does the same "check" if the iframe is loaded and loads the first video over and over again.
when i remove the "load" event from my code i dont have the problem with the videos getting messed up, i have no problem.

also tried to remove the class when the load event runs the first time but no luck.

sorry if this was long and poorly explaned..

[Jsfiddle of the carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/5gQ8e/5/)

Comment: btw. the fiddle is just to show how the carousel works...

Comment: Have you tried using `one()`: `$(".firstVid").one('load',...);`???